# Google Cloud Run deploy failed: error during container import

Tags: deployment, containers, gcloud

When trying to deploy a new revision in Google Cloud Run, it fails and I see following error messages:

> Creating revision: Revision XXX is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again later. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.

> The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again later. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.

Also redeploying the image of the current version fails, while it was successfully deployed a week ago.

What could be the problem?
Is there a way to see loggings of what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know what the root of the problem was, I was able to solve it by

1. Deploying a new revision with "Serve this revision immediately" disabled
2. Moving the traffic to the newly deployed revision